# Modify an event already on the calendar in Fullcalendar is possible?

Tags: fullcalendar

Hello i'm trying to work with Fullcalendar (from here http://fullcalendar.io) but I don't find if I can change or delete an event already planning on calendar just by clicking on the event area to edit or delete it ? is that possible ? Thanks for your answers

I'll try this at the bottom of my calendar.html file

```
$(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

        alert('Event: ' + calEvent.title);
        alert('Coordinates: ' + jsEvent.pageX + ',' + jsEvent.pageY);
        alert('View: ' + view.name);

        // change the border color just for fun
        $(this).css('border-color', 'red');

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

1) Use `eventClick:` to trigger your function when the user clicks on the event.

2) Modify the event properties as necessary, e.g. `event.title = "Test";`

3) Call `updateEvent` on fullCalendar's div, with your modified event as the parameter.